# Can´t compare two strings in python

Tags: python, string, text-files

I need to check if thre is a call for a function, I know it's not a txt file but when I read a line and try to print using type() it's says str and let me to print all the file correctly but for whatever reason the lines can't be compare and I don't know why, when I compile shows no error, the first line of the file is `'#include <Arduino.h>'` and the var found is false anyways

```
import os
def BeforeBuild():
    found = False
    with open(r"\src\OTAWEBAP.cpp", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            print (line)
            if(line == '#include <Arduino.h>'):
                found = True;
        if(not found):
            raise Exception("OtaIni function not found, you need to use it to preserve OTA functions in your new deploy")
        else:
            print('function OtaIni was found')
    f.close()
BeforeBuild()
```

Comment: Search this. '#include <Arduino.h>\n'

Comment: What does ``print(line)`` return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing

```
if(line == '#include <Arduino.h>'):
            found = True;
```

with

```
if line.strip() == '#include <Arduino.h>':
    found = True
```

The strip() function removes ALL whitespace at the beginning and end of the line.

P. S. Try to remember that in Python, if conditions don't need to be in parenthesis and lines don't need semicolons at the end.  Otherwise everyone will know that you're really a C programmer at heart.

Answer (score 1):

**The last character is `\n` if you change the line.**

**So this may work for you:-**

```py
import os
def BeforeBuild():
    found = False
    with open(r"\src\OTAWEBAP.cpp", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            print (line)
            if(line[:-1] == '#include <Arduino.h>'):
                found = True;
        if(not found):
            raise Exception("OtaIni function not found, you need to use it to preserve OTA functions in your new deploy")
        else:
            print('function OtaIni was found')
    f.close()
BeforeBuild()
```

Comment: it works now I have another problem, now I'm trying with the real line with 
`if(line[:-1] == 'OtaIni();'):`
but now Ihave the same problem, the line is in the file and if Idebug the var line has the string but the compare didn't work

Comment: Use `if(line.strip() == 'OtaIni();'):` as @Paul Cornelius suggested because `line[:-1]` removes the last item even if it is not a `whitespace` so `line[:-1]` works only in specific case. Or, `line = line.strip()` also works fine as @Shabbir Hossain suggested.

Comment: thank you all for the help, now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Caution should be taken while comparing strings. In this case a **whitespace** character causing this issue. There are a lot of **whitespace** characters that could not be seen but may present. So, a good practice while working with this kind of files is to remove these **whitespace** characters.
You can use **strip()** to remove **whitespace** characters from both end of a string.

```
import os
def BeforeBuild():
    found = False
    with open(r"\src\OTAWEBAP.cpp", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip();
            print (line)
            if line == '#include <Arduino.h>':
                found = True;
        if not found:
            raise Exception("OtaIni function not found, you need to use it to preserve OTA functions in your new deploy")
        else:
            print('function OtaIni was found')
    f.close()
BeforeBuild()
```